# How to validate negative values with hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a table that contains the stock. It's legacy database and the stock is kept in columns. The database has a constraint on the columns stating that they can't be negative values. But I only get the constrain violation after the Transaction is committed.

```
15:21:31,154  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 2290, SQLState: 23000
15:21:31,154 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - ORA-02290: check constraint (ERPDSS13.STKMAST_CON_QTY13) violated
ORA-06512: at "ERPDSS13.INLTRAN_UPD_STKMAST", line 25
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ERPDSS13.INLTRAN_UPD_STKMAST'
```

Is there a way with annotations you can specify that a column can't be negative. Below is the column mapping?

```
@Column(name = "STKSOHQTY01", precision = 12)
public BigDecimal getStksohqty01() {
    return this.stksohqty01;
}
```

Comment: <hibernate.version>3.5.4-Final</hibernate.version>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Check(constraints = "STKSOHQTY01 >= 0")  
public class Coupon implements  Serializable {

}
```

It should work

Comment: Where will the exception will be thrown?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.5 Hibernate supports standard [bean validation (JSR303)](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html). You can and should use those to validate your entities as the API is fast, well-integrated, and more importantly, *standardized*:

```
@Min(value = 0)
@Column(name = "STKSOHQTY01", precision = 12)
public BigDecimal getStksohqty01() {
    return this.stksohqty01;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@Check`

```
@Check(constraints = "STKSOHQTY01t >= 0")

public class YourEntity implements  Serializable {...}
```